# C# Make properties visible if a condition is satisfied

Tags: c#, oop

I finally went on and started studying OOP principles and I am currently making a simple game.
Here is the situation:
I have one abstract class called Items that holds all the possible attributes of an item as properties and the quality of the item as an enumeration:

```
public enum ItemQuality
{
    Common,
    Uncommon,
    Rare,
    Epic,
    Legendary
}

public abstract class Items
{
    public ItemQuality ItemQuality { get; set; }
    public int Stamina { get; set; }
    public int Strength { get; set; }
    public int Agility { get; set; }
    public int Intelligence { get; set; }
    public int Damage { get; set; }
    public int Block { get; set; }
    public int Armor { get; set; }
}
```

I have two more classes called Weapon and Armor (they inherit the Items class) and they hold the WeaponType and ArmorType respectively, both of which are also enumerations.

Consider the following scenario: I make a new Weapon of type Sword, I am able to give it a value for Blocking, but it's a weapon it can't block. I want to make different properties visible depending on the Weapon/Armor type.

```
Weapon weapon = new Weapon();
weapon.WeaponType = WeaponType.Sword;
weapon.Block = 5;
```

In this case I shouldn't be able to see the Block property.

To go even further I don't want to have to instantiate Weapons and Armors separately from the Character (I also have a Character class).

My end goal is to do something like this:

```
Character character = new Character();
character.WeaponType = WeaponType.Sword;
character.WeaponType.Damage = 10;
```

Or something like this, I am not even sure if my structure is correct so I am open to suggestions!
Thanks!

Comment: Consider using interfaces instead and use composition instead inheritance.

Comment: Maybe the decorator pattern might be something for you. So you could wrap the base class with a decorator containing the additionally needed properties

Comment: Thanks guys! Seems like I have a lot more to learn :)

Comment: What you are doing here is breaking the Listov Substitution Principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Defining a base class with everything in it and then selectively trying to hide things is the complete opposite of "best practice". Instead, please follow @JanneMatikainen's advice and learn about interfaces and composition, rather than inheritance.

Comment: In your given scenario it would be better to have the Damage, Block, etc properties in the child classes. This way only weapons have damage etc.

Comment: You're trying to jam your game mechanics in a class hierarchy. It's probably a) not possible to achieve every thing you want through this and b) probably not a good idea. OOP is fine, but inheritance is not the alpha and omega of programming. Try reading the [wizards and warriors](http://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/) series of articles by Eric Lippert. It's very educational.

Comment: [chat] , [answer] Maybe you can declare the property "Protected" . then you can create other properties in child class to manage them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget inheritance here and use composition. For example, start with the basics:

public enum ItemQuality
{
    Common,
    Uncommon,
    Rare,
    Epic,
    Legendary
}

```
public class Item
{
    public ItemQuality ItemQuality { get; set; }

    // other things common to all items here

    public List<IFeature> features { get; set; }
}
```

So what is `IFeature`. Well to start with, it's an empty interface:

```
public interface IFeature { }
```

But let's now start adding weapons:

```
public interface IAttackWeapon : IFeature
{
    int Damage { get; set; }
}

public interface IDefenceWeapon : IFeature
{
    int Block { get; set; }
}
```

We can then start defining some classes:

```
public class Weapon : IAttackWeapon
{
    public Damage { get; set }
}

public class Shield : IDefenceWeapon
{
    public int Block { get; set; }
}
```

So then, I might define some weapons:

```
public static readonly Item ShortSword = new Item
{
    ItemQuality = ItemQuality.Common,
    Cost = 5,
    Features = new List<IFeature>
    {
        new Weapon { Damage = 4 }
    }
}
```

By taking this composition approach, if we say want a magic sword at a later date, we do not need to create lots more classes, lots more properties to hide etc. Nor do we run into problems of "should my magic sword inherit from weapon or magic item?". Instead, we'd add a new feature, eg:

```
public static readonly Item MagicSword = new Item
{
    ItemQuality = ItemQuality.Rare,
    Cost = 5000,
    Features = new List<IFeature>
    {
        new Weapon { Damage = 10 },
        new MagicItem { Spell = Spells.TurnToFrog }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it looks good. I will look deeper into interfaces now. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would not choose that way especially if you want to maintain good OOP.

Why won`t you use interfaces for example one IAttackable and IBlockable. A shield would implement the IBlockable interface only, a sword IAttackable and IBlockable and a Gun only IAttackable

You would be abe to ask if the weapon object is blockable

```
   if (currentWeapon is IBlockable)
   {
        var blockWeapon = currentWeapon as IBlockable;
        blockWeapon.blockHorizontal();
        blockWeapon.blockVertical();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to OOP principles, it is a bad design to define object type as an enumerator. Good OOP would make use of inheritance and possibly polymorphism. Like that:

```
public abstract class Weapon {
    public int cost {get; set;}
}
public class Sword : Weapon {
    public int damage {get; set;}
}
public class Shield : Weapon {
    public int defense {get; set;}
}
```

Now you can say:

```
Sword blade = new Sword();
blade.cost = 5;
blade.damage = 6;

Shield myShield = new Shield();
myShield.cost = 4;
myShield.defense = 7;
```

If you need a new type of a weapon you may subclass Weapon class like we did with Sword and Shield (let's say, you want Bow).
If you need another attacking weapon like knife, you may subclass Sword, for example.

```
public class Knife {
    public int length {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: So I should make a new class for every type of item (armor, weapon)?
If I do that then I would need to instantiate every class, right?

Comment: Yes, good OOP suggests separate class for every TYPE. Then you can have as many instances as you want of that class, like an array of swords, for example.

Comment: But I don't want that. If I do that I will have to instantiate 15 objects for each of the classes like Armor chest = new Armor(); then another one for headguard another one for legguard and so on, instead I want all items to be accessible from my character instance of the Character class. Similarly to the last few rows from my main post.

Comment: Again, good OOP design comes with more code but it is highly maintainable. In your case you can have Weapon property in your Character class and than say myChar.weapon = new Sword(); (Sword)myChar.weapon.damage = 5; OR myChar.weapon = new Shield(); (Shield)myChar.weapon.degense = 3;

Comment: This is NOT good design. You are leading the OP down the classic path to OO headaches here. What happens if I want a weapon that has both a damage and defense value? I'd have to extend one or other of `Sword` or `Shield` and would then end up with two non-polymorphic definitions of either `damage` or `defense`.

Comment: David is correct but the argument of instantiate an object each time a new piece of armor is needed is the right way to do it. Each time there is a different item there should be a separate object.